# Multiple form_fors on page is causing issues with the _method attribute

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml, rails-routing, form-for

*Rewrite*

I have 2 models. App and Conversation.
An app contains multiple conversations

```
resources :apps do
    resources :conversations
end
```

I have a single view which with 2 forms on them using the form for tag.
The first form is for updating the app model.
The other is for creating or updating a conversation.

The issue I am having is that when I use the form_for tag, the resulting html is not generating the _method input.

EG
Conversation Form.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/apps/50c87614e976a31149000009/conversations" class="new_conversation ng-pristine ng-valid" id="new_conversation" method="post">

 <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="RqwwgBb737uuwg3PgRS+z0qlOP1aDqWe+2hrEeU0KHk=">
</div>
```

App Form

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/apps/50c87614e976a31149000009" class="edit_app ng-pristine ng-valid" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_app_50c87614e976a31149000009" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="RqwwgBb737uuwg3PgRS+z0qlOP1aDqWe+2hrEeU0KHk="></div>
```

---

Lets just focus on the conversation model for now as this is the one having the issue.

From the html above, you would expect that the Conversation form should send a post request. Unfortunately when it is received by the rails app, it is treated as a puts request.

Looking at the documentation for form_for I know that form_for is supposed to set a hidden input field called _method.

If you look at the Conversation form and compare it to the App form, you can see that the conversation does not have the _method attribute. I cannot determine why this is.

Has anyone any ideas why this is being ignored? Or why when I submit the conversation form, a puts is being sent instead of a post?

Comment: What does the controller look like? What about the routes?

Comment: @PerfectlyNormal The controller and routes are your standard rest routes defined as resources. However controller routes are nested inside apps. See the updated question for what I mean. Why do you ask?

Comment: I asked since it looks like it should work fine, but since it doesn't, then looking at the rest of the code would probably be helpful. 

`form_for` only sets the `_method`-field if the request should be treated as something other than POST, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @PerfectlyNormal Thats what I figured too. Can you think of any scenario where the app form's _method field would be able to bleed over into the other?

Comment: Possibly some kind of JavaScript that doesn't do what it should. Other than that, I don't really know.

Comment: @PerfectlyNormal My other question about javascript is an attempt at debugging the problem. Not a potential cause. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Rails implements an HTTP put as post form with a hidden input called `_method` which has a value of `put`. You should see that hidden input in the form that is being processed as a PUT request.

`form_for` will generate a put form when the object it is creating a form for already exists.

Comment: I have updated the question, please take a look.

Does the same _method still get created when the object does not exist? EG _method => 'post'

Eg the above should post